# How to Get Route Data from Middleware for ASPNETCORE OData request?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-middleware

I have the following Middleware class which gets the route data for the current request.

If you perform a Get on the Values Controller you will see the context.GetRouteData() returns a value and is not null. I have wired Swagger\Swashbuckle into the attached project to make this easier to demo.

However, if you call the Blog OData controller (http://localhost:40946/odata/Blog), context.GetRouteData() returns null.

Does anyone know how to access the RouteData from middleware for an OData request?

```
public class TestMiddleware
{
    protected readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next;
    }

    public virtual async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var routeData = context.GetRouteData();

        await this._next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

[Link to sample solution demonstrating the issue](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvEvR5mmIqrDlkoc6gws62gQUKp3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the OData Middleware isn't providing the routing info as a IRoutingFeature to the context. [Link to Source Code](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions/RoutingHttpContextExtensions.cs)

Not sure the root cause - but as a workaround you could use

```
var httpRequestFeature = context.Features[typeof(IHttpRequestFeature)] as IHttpRequestFeature;
var path = httpRequestFeature?.Path;
```